# Can we block opening CSS, JS files?

Tags: html, css, blocking

It is very common we link CSS and JS files in out HTML, PHP pages. Can we block opening of the CSS and JS files directly from a browser. Since the source code can be viewed by anyone, he/she can open those files by understanding the path. How can we achieve blocking these files?

Comment: You can't.  If the user couldn't read them the web browser wouldn't be able to read them.

Comment: All you can do is obfuscate the files, but that doesn't really keep a user from reusing them as-is.

Comment: Say for example we can set 403 permission for folders such as www.websitename.com/images. But still the files/images under the tree are still accessible.

Comment: Why would you bother the user opening the file? If you're placing sensitive information in javascript, well, that's your fault entirely...

Comment: Obfuscation is the solution. People will write code rather than trying to read obfucated code :) try you self [here online obfuscator](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm)

Comment: @Andre Yep!!! The user must be blocked to open the file such as www.websitename.com/css/filename.css. So that they cannot reuse it. This is just an example. I just need to utilize the technique for all other type of files.

Comment: @Andre: The reason why I tried to block is not security issue. People try to download the files inside a tree using DOWNLOAD MANAGER and SITE GRABBERS. So if we were able to block then only genuine requests can be served.

Comment: I wonder, could you show users an image of the styled page they're getting and after they fulfill whatever requirements there are, email them a direct link to the CSS/page, or perhaps email it as an attachment (zip maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the following resource, they might help.

http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

http://www.n1studios.net/tutorials/php/css-file-protection.html

all of them are somehow way around, and **there is always a way to read them**. you can only make them hard to read

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your web server to server the static content (js, img, css) only if refered by your host (looking at the http headers), but it won't totally prevent user from doing it.  as for the `php` users won't see it, it runs on the server, and will output most of the times inert `html`.

Comment: There's a major issue with this. If the browser is set to not send the referrer header, then if you require it to be present and set to the site these people cannot view any resources.

Comment: What I'm saying is: without the referrer header set the user cannot see the resources, period. So if I had my system going through a proxy that strips this, or I configured my browser this way, then I cannot see anything protected like this.

Answer (score 1):

A basic block would force the browser to send a valid `Referer` header when accessing the files. This can be done with some simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !your\.domain\.here [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

However this is not a great idea because it's easy enough to fake the referrer, or add a link to the page so that the browser naturally sends it. Also, some browsers just don't show the referrer header.

Comment: IME, this doesn't work that well with Firefox... at least not older versions.

Comment: I would appreciate your comments on my answer

Answer (score 1):

The browser has to be able to access those files in order to properly display the page. You can obfuscate the JS, either through something basic like minification, or something more complex like [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

With CSS, you can try something similar.